# Hiding folder in URL using HTACCESS

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess

I have a domain like "360research.pchealth.ca", where if user hits "360research.pchealth.ca/admin", system will go into ADMIN folder, but what I need that if user hit "360research.pchealth.ca" it goes to ADMIN but don't show in URL that user is in ADMIN folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} 360research\.pchealth\.ca [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /admin/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Is it fine if I need to trail:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} 360research\.pchealth\.ca/system/research/canadian/ [NC]

Comment: @Umer `/system/research/canadian/` isn't part of the HOST, so that condition will always fail.

Comment: Just a Q: What if I have "admin" directory exit under

360research.pchealth.ca/system/research/canadian/admin

and now wants

360research.pchealth.ca/system/research/canadian/
to read in
360research.pchealth.ca/system/research/canadian/admin/

Comment: @Umer then replace the `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /admin/$1 [L]` rule with `RewriteRule ^system/research/canadian/(.*)$ /system/research/canadian/admin/$1 [L]` and the condition to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/system/research/canadian/admin/`